# In the bath of Janaba, are the anal hairs required to be washed?

Tags: ghusl

I heard that in the bath of Janaba, no hair can be kept dry.

So, in the above description, are the anal hairs included?

Comment: From whom have you heard that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really fussy and unbelievably complicated and sounds hardly going along with the teaching of Islam.

> Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship (2:185 https://quranx.com/2.185)

The prophet () only poured three times water on his body (or more exactly over his head as from there it usually goes down and reaches the rest of the body) for ghusl. The point is that ghusl in Arabic means pouring water and for a ghusl the water should reach all about your body (parts), and the effort of doing so is already enough to make the ghusl corerct and valid.